# trying to determine unique identifier for database table

Tags: sql

I have a database table with many columns and there is no specified primary key. There isn't a list of super keys either. Besides iteratively trying all candidate keys/columns, is there a way for me, using SQL, to try and figure our whether a subset of keys can make a unique identifier for my table?

For example, a table may have 4 columns first name, last name, address and zip and the data I see is:

```
John, Smith, 1 main st, 00001  
Mary, Smith, 1 main st, 00001  
Mary, Smith, 2 sub st, 00002
```

In this case, I'll need first, last and zip as my unique key.

```
John, Smith, 1 main st, 00001  
John, Smith, 1 main st, 00001
```

In this case, there is no unique key.

Please don't comment on my table construction and/or normalization of databases, I'm just trying to find a practical answer. Thanks.

This is my question: Besides iteratively trying all candidate keys/columns, is there a way for me, using SQL, to try and figure our whether a subset of keys can make a unique identifier for my table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot find if a combination "can" make a primary key. You can find if one WILL make a good primary key for an existing set of data.

To find if a set of fields is candidate or not, you can count the distinct of those fields (using group-by with rollup) and compare that with `count (*)`

Answer (score 5):

Looking for a subset of unique values in this case seems so specific to the particular data set. What if you arrive at a subset today and find you can't insert a new row tomorrow?

Use an artificial key, like an auto-incrementing integer.

Comment: Thanks. I'm actually trying to compare two databases but cannot find a key to compare them on.

Comment: While I belive in artifical keys, if you havea natural key that should be enfoced inthe database with a unique constraint. Just creating an artifical key to avoid having to analyze the data is a poor practice.

Answer (score 4):

In short: no, there's no way to do this in T-SQL really.

My advice: just add a `ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY` column to the table. It's guaranteed to be unique, it will be filled automagically when you create it, it's fast and easy, no messy "is this really unique or are there any combinations of rows that violate the uniqueness" questions......

Just do it - it's the easiest way to go!!

Answer (score 3):

There is a **much faster** method.

Enterprise dbms have had it for many years but MS SQL Server 2005 (useable in 2008) and later provided the [**HashBytes()**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415%28SQL.90%29.aspx) function. Convert the columns to CHAR() (VARCHAR on MS), concatenate them; then hash them; then compare the hashes.  You can compare the two tables in a single `SELECT` command. IIRC max 8000 characters per row.

(If you use this answer, please undo and redo your Answer choice.)

Answer (score 2):

if you are comparing two databases, then you can see if any duplicate rows exist in the source db with structures like this:

```
select a,b,c,d
from mytable
having count(*) > 1
group by a,b,c,d
```

include all columns.

then use all columns as the 'row key' to see if it exists in the target system

Answer (score 0):

there are update anomalies in this schema:
you cannot a person without knowing his address

better approach is to separate to three tables, one for persons and one for PersonAddress

```
> perons: id,firstname, lastname
> address: id,address:
> personaddress: personid, addressid
```

Comment: the OP doesn't seem to be open to changing data structures

Comment: this will get you in to trouble later when the dataset grows

Comment: "you cannot [add?] a person without knowing his address?" Thanks for the comment, I didn't set up the DB thus have no control over its schema.

Comment: what will you do if two persons with the same name live in the same location and have the same zip code?

Comment: Then I'd be sad and won't have a unique identifier (as in my second example) :(

Answer (score 0):

> You cannot find if a combination "can" make a primary key.

I actually disagree with this, I think it is possible to write a query that will SELECT all possible permutations of columns from the table and combine each permutation into a single unique value (the simplest, crudest way is to CAST them all to VARCHAR and connect them with a spacer character - a better way would be some kind of hash function).

With a single pass you would then have set of columns like P1, P12, P123, P2, P23, P3 etc (in case of three columns). Then you can do a query with COUNT(*) vs COUNT(DISTINCT) for each permutation column and you will see which permutations are unique.

Using dynamic SQL you could probably make it so that it would work on any table, although I don't know about the column limit for SQL Server.

Comment: Although I agree with n8wrl of course that you cannot be certain if these permutations are supposed to stay unique in the future or not.

Comment: Sure.  But it will take you a year or two to right that query.  That's why OP is looking for something else.